# Find a 2-by-2 real matrix $A$ with the property that $x_T A x$ > 0 for all real nonzero 2-vectors but $A $ is not positive definite in complex field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a 2-by-2 real matrix $A$ with the property that $$x^T Ax > 0$$ for all real nonzero 2-vectors
but which is not positive definite when regarded as a member of $\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$

Comment: What have you tried?  If nothing else, write it out componentwise and set it equal to $-1$.  See what happens when $x$ is real.  See if you can solve the equation if the elements of $x$ are complex

Comment: suggested exercise: prove $\mathbf x^* A \mathbf x \in \mathbb R$ for all $\mathbf x \in \mathbb C^n \iff A$ is Hermitian.  Being positive definite is a special case of all quadratic forms being real.

Comment: Consider a matrix which is obviously positive definite, for example $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 &2\end{pmatrix}$$ Then observe that  for $x$ real the quadratic form $x^TAx$ depends only on $a_{12}+a_{21},$ so you can play with that to spoil positive definitness.